# Rotate Triangle To Z = 0

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, geometry

im trying to make a hole into a triangle in 3D space using XNA.
I want to convert this problem to 2D space.
But i dont know how to rotate the triangle that all the points have Z = 0.
Point1 has the coordinats X=0,Y=0,Z=0.
Anyone know a solution?
LG
Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `P1`, `P2`, `P3` the points of the triangle.

Let's note:

- `a = P2 - P1`
- `b = P3 - P1`
- `n = Vector3.CrossProduct(a, b).Normalized()`  -> `n` is the normal of the triangle

The triangle is in the `Z = 0` plane if and only of, `n.z = 0`
Then, just use:

- `d = Vector3.CrossProduct(n, z).Normalized()` -> it is the axis of your rotation
- `angle = (float)System.Math.Acos(Vector3.DotProduct(n, z))` -> it is the angle of your rotation

The code is:

```
Vector3 a = P2 - P1;
Vector3 b = P3 - P1;
Vector3 n = Vector3.Cross(a, b);
n.Normalize();
Vector3 d = Vector3.Cross(n, Vector3.UnitZ);
d.Normalize();
float angle = (float)System.Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(n, Vector3.UnitZ));

Vector3 newpoint2 = P1 + Vector3.Transform(a, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(d, angle));
Vector3 newpoint3 = P1 + Vector3.Transform(b, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(d, angle));
```

Comment: d = Vector3.CrossProduct(n, z) -> it is the axis of your rotation. What is z?

Comment: Vector3 P1 = AVertex[Dreieck1.A];
            Vector3 P2 = AVertex[Dreieck1.B];
            Vector3 P3 = AVertex[Dreieck1.C];

            Vector3 a = P2 - P1;
            Vector3 b = P3 - P1;
            Vector3 n1 = Vector3.Cross(a, b);
            Vector3 n = Vector3.Normalize(n1);
            Vector3 d = Vector3.Cross(n,Vector3.UnitZ);
            double angle = System.Math.Acos(Vector3.Dot(n,Vector3.UnitZ));
            Vector3 newpoint = Vector3.Transform(P2, Matrix.CreateRotationX((float)angle));                               like this? but the z is not 0 z :/

Comment: You don't use _d_. _Vector3 newpoint = Vector3.Transform(P2, Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(d, (float)angle * 180 / 3.1415926535f))_

Comment: @Jens Sorry, I though angle with in degree but it is in radians. I update my post.

Comment: well but my result is still not 0 its 128

Comment: P1 has its Z value set to 0?

Comment: OK, I though P1 was = (0, 0, 0) I change the code in few seconds ;)

Comment: Ty, the result is {X:64 Y:768 Z:2,797529E-05} and {X:0 Y:768 Z:2,797529E-05} i dont think the result is right?

Comment: @Jens 2,797529E-05 = 0.000027 is extremely close to 0. You can't have a better precision.

Answer (score 0):

1. Pick one of the points that's not at (0,0,0).  Rotate the shape around the y axis until the z value of that point is 0.
2. Pick the remaining point.  Rotate the shape around the X axis until the z value of that point is 0.

Comment: i will try it, but i think this would not be good in performance?

Comment: @Jens It was just a first thought.  If you find another algorithm that's much quicker, then by all means use that.